# Open the login page in a remote popup - OCTOBER CMS

Tags: octobercms

I'm trying to create a link that allows the users to open the login page in a modal popup.

According to this documentation https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/popup,
using the `data-ajax` attribute I could refer to an external file or URL directly.

So since the URL of my login page is `{{ 'login'|page }}`

I aspect that writing something like the code below would make it happen.

```
<a
    data-control="popup"
    data-ajax="{{ 'login'|page }}"
    href="javascript:;"
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
    Launch Ajax Form
</a>
```

But when I click on the link nothing is happening.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share console log ect

Comment: it seems nothing get printed in the console log..

Comment: are you including OC ajax framework -> https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction can you please check that once

Comment: Yes I'm doing it